# Vue 2 toggle class for below element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to toggle the class of another div on click.

Something like:

```
<div class="link">
 <p> Click here to show the content </p>
 <div class="content">
  <p>This is the hidden content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

so content css should initially be: display: none

How can I do this on vue, when p is clicked, toggle the element below.

thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use css classes for this if you use the [`v-show` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show):

```
<div class="link">
  <p @click="show = true"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your Vue component, you just need to add a `show` property that is initially set to `false`:

```
data() {
  return {
    show: false,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this... I didn't know this, but how to do conditional toggle now, because once I click it just shows, I want to be able to toggle on each click

Comment: thnx a lot for your help, I have another questions related.. I have many same div, about 10, and I want to be able once <div class="link"> is clicked, I want to show just it's content and not other related divs... is that possible ?

Comment: <div class="link">
  <p @click="show = true"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: I would make this into it's own reusable component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html